# offset with SMA function

Tags: pine-script

I am very new to Pine Scripting and trying my hands with first basic strategy. I would like to include offset with SMA function in pine script.

Any help on how to do that?

Appreciate your inputs.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `offset` argument of the `plot` [function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plot)?

```
//@version=4
study("sma50 + offset")

sma50 = sma(close, 50)
plot(sma50, offset = 20)
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I am trying to use offset in a function as below: 

sma13h = sma(high, 13)

Comment: offset is a plot's argument. Plot your sma13h variable  with an offset argument as in the example above